Children samplers are displayed under transaction controller in HTML report although Generate parent sampler is enabled
Children samplers are displayed under transaction controller in HTML report although Generate parent sampler is enabled.

I have configured the below property related to subresults to false in user.properties file.

jmeter.save.saveservice.subresults=false

Filtered the results in HTML report as well using below in jmeter property file but still child samples are displayed.

jmeter.reportgenerator.exporter.html.series_filter=^((?!Sample).)*$
